# somar valores de uma tabela e colocar o resultado em outra

Tags: mysql

Possuo uma tabela chamada players e preciso somar os valores da coluna pontos mas somente das que possuírem o mesmo account_id e após colocar o resultado em outra tabela chamada accounts justamente na qual possuir o id indicado. O resultado seria esse:

Tabela players:

```
account_id    |pontos      
1             |50  
1             |100               
2             |25              
2             |20
```

Tabela accounts:

```
id            |pontos      
1             |150
2             |45
```

Comment: Você precisa de um `INSERT INTO SELECT`. Ficarei devendo agora o SQL, mas fica a dica para quem puder te responder com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente isso:

```
INSERT INTO accounts values (select account_id as id, SUM(pontos) from players group by account_id);
```

Comment: Tentei mas fica dando o seguinte erro: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
Esqueci de mencionar que pode já haver valores dentro da coluna pontos na tabela accounts, então nessa situação os pontos deveriam também serem somados.

Comment: Consegui da seguinte forma:

UPDATE accounts, players 
SET accounts.pontos = ( accounts.pontos + ( SELECT SUM(pontos) 
FROM players WHERE players.pontos > 0 AND players.account_id = accounts.id
GROUP BY account_id ) ) 
WHERE players.pontos > 0 AND players.account_id = accounts.id;

De qualquer forma ajudou muito no desenvolvimento. Obrigado.

Comment: Ah, o erro de syntax acredito que era a palavra values antes do select, era só remover ela.